# Get a file path C#

Tags: c#, directory, filepath

I have a .txt file that I need to read in my program. For the moment I have the directory hardcoded as such:

```
file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\<username>\Documents\File.txt");
```

However that will (obviously) not work on any other PC that does not have that access to altering the code, or (by some strange happenstance) the same directory as the original code.

How can I get the full file path to set it in my program using C#?

Comment: Use `Application.StartupPath` to keep the `File.txt`

Comment: @Grant The file will be in a specified location, eg. My Documents or in the location the program is installed, but I don't want the user to access the file readily.

Comment: @Hassan could you expand on that? As far as I know all `Application.StartupPath` will return is the directory for the program, not the .txt file.

Comment: @Ben yes directory of executable then you have combine the path with `File.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the file in their Application Data directory (they could still find it if they wanted to, but at least it wouldn't be as obvious as the My Documents folder).

When you want to access it, use the `Environment` class. There are methods for locating special folders for the current user, without resorting to hard-coded paths:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
                   Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "File.txt");
```

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant, but what do I use in place of "Path"?

Comment: Path, he means, is `System.IO.Path`, you need a reference to `System.IO`

Comment: Actually I believe "Environment" belongs in `System.Collections`

Comment: Add `using System.IO;` while `System` namespace is mostly there by default.

Comment: Oddly enough this returns "C:\Users\<username>\Appdata\Roaming\File.txt". Would this be a problem?

Comment: That returns "C:\Users\<username>\Appdata\Local\File.txt". I was hoping to get the original file path, but this works anyway so it's not a problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: When I use this in a `StreamReader` it gives me an error "Cannot find file '<File Path>'. this is both with the "Roaming" and "Local" directories

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**:

[`Application.StartupPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used for the purpose.

It gets the path for the executable file that started the application, not including the executable name.

Keep `File.txt` with your executable.

**Option 2**:

Use [`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

It gives directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user.

**NOTE**: If you want to restrict the user to look into the contents of File.txt then you might need to encrypt the contents.